# Android Studio - Error with V-23 file - Unable to compile

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an app in Android Studio and have been for several weeks now. **I am wanting SDK 21, not 23!** SDK 21 has been working for the past few weeks with no problems at all

This morning, I have retuned to my PC to carry on with my programming, went to run the application and these errors appeared:

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that 
matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the 
given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

Between the app working last night and trying to run the app this morning - nothing has changed. I haven't even closed down android studio. I left my PC on sleep.

I have searched stack overflow and noticed that these errors have occurred for others too. I have tried the answers that have been given to others such as checking the project structure, dependencies, gradle file etc. I have also tried the standard clean and build

This is my Gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.package"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
productFlavors {
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

[image: Build Project Screen Shot]

[image: Project Structure Screen Shot]

Apologies for the images being links, I'm new to SO so can't embed them to a post yet.

It's completely possible that I am missing something obvious but I have been trying to solve this problem for the past few hours and I'm not getting anywhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Stand Alone SDK Manager Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX0Nk.png)

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJjpP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

This dependency requires the `23.0.0` version of the `support-v4` library (FWIW, 8.3 and 8.1 require `22.2.0`, hence you are compiling with the API 23 versions of the Support Library.

Keep in mind though, the best practice, as described in the [Picking your compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and minSdkVersion](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) is to **always compile with the latest SDK**:

> It should be emphasized that **changing your compileSdkVersion does not change runtime behavior.** While new compiler warnings/errors may be present when changing your compileSdkVersion, your compileSdkVersion is not included in your APK: it is purely used at compile time. *(You should really fix those warnings though — they were added for a reason!)*
>
> Therefore it is strongly recommended that you **always compile with the latest SDK.** You’ll get all the benefits of new compilation checks on existing code, avoid newly deprecated APIs, and be ready to use new APIs.

Therefore the easiest solution is to change your `compileSdkVersion` to API 23, while leaving your `targetSdkVersion` (what controls runtime behavior and use of things like runtime permissions) at whatever level you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.1.0'
```

Comment: Just tried this. Unfortunately the error is still there after syncing

Comment: are you sure you never made a change on any settings? Can you please post me a screenshot of the standalone SDK Manager showing the version numbers of the installed packages? like support library etc?

Comment: DevTest, I have had to add it as a link to my original post. Please see the link at the bottom of my question

Comment: @lou2216 Please add Image of Support Library also / Verify the version number of support library in SDK Manager as 21.1.0

Comment: I have added a screen shot of my dependencies - this includes the support lib. Is this what you're after? Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I thought of playservics dependency, but couldn't verify my conclusion. But I think @ianhanniballake answered it! and that might solve your issue.

upgrading your targetsdk and compilesdk version does no harm at all :-)